# Android YouTubePlayerView unauthorized overlay and too small error

Tags: android, youtube-api

I'm using Youtube Api for Android in my app, and i create new YouTubePlayerView dynamic in my activity such as:

```
YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = new  YouTubePlayerView(PlayerActivity.this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(640, 360);
layoutParams.setMargins(100, 200, 0, 0);
youTubePlayerView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
root.addView(youTubePlayerView);
```

As the code, "root" is a RelativeLayout, and the size and margin of youTubePlayerView is different with each youTubePlayerView;

this code sometimes work, but sometimes not, it returns error below:

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView{37ab2582 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 (these should all be positive).
```

or this one

```
W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to the player's view being too small. The YouTubePlayerView is 0dp wide (minimum is 200dp) and 0dp high (minimum is 110dp).
```

is there any way to avoid it happen, or let it play video successfully.

i appreciate any help.

Regards

Comment: do you still experiencing the issue?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Official Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer), setting the flag leaves to you the task of handling the UI elements visibility.

YouTube player will detect that a view is being displayed over it and will throw that warning.

You can try with one of the following additional flags:

[FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#Constants):causes the player to automatically enter fullscreen whenever the device enters landscape orientation.

[FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_ORIENTATION](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#Constants): enables automatic control of the orientation.

[FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CONTROL_SYSTEM_UI](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#Constants%5C): enables automatic control of system UI.

[FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer#Constants):disables the default fullscreen layout handler, enabling you to control the transition to fullscreen layout manually.